# JDBC - Handle Oracle Complexity Stored Procedure

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures, spring-jdbc

I have a task to send **Sales Transaction Data** in one go connection. So I decided to use Oracle Stored Procedure with XMLtype data type as IN parameter. **I wonder if it is bad practice?**

The **Oracle Stored Procedure** that I wrote have INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE with bunch of repetitions. I do that because the project sources is using Spring auto-commit and I can't change that configuration because of company reasons.

Comment: no it's not a bad practice

Comment: @Leo thanks, Am I over thinking there is no other way to solve my task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like it is supported:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96620/xdb04cre.htm

Comment: I know if oracle support XMLType, the one that I wonder is "it is okay? or there are other ways to solve it.", btw thanks for the link